# Signed Numbers or δᵟ

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx pattern to validate input. Signed/unsigned integers, floats, numbers with scientific notation OR one of δᵟ (each δ has unique unicode) are allowed.

The pattern I have created is:

This is a requirement for specifying charge on an atom in a molecule. Sample valid values are: 1, -1, +2.123e-5, .001, -.001, 0.003, 1., 1.0, -δ, +δ, δ- and δ+. Numbers and δ are mutually exclusive.

```
^[-+]?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|[-+]?[δᵟ]?
```

It seems to work but I'm not 100% sure. I wonder if there's a better pattern for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that values like `.1` or `.123` are not matched by your current pattern, so instead of the subpattern `[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*` you have to use something like `([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)` that ensures at least one digit.

About the part `[-+]?[δᵟ]?`, it doesn't seem correct, since it matches a single hyphen. To obtain what you want you must describe the three cases (the sign is before, after or nowhere): `[δᵟ][-+]?|[-+][δᵟ]`

So, *in fine*, the correct pattern is probably:

```
([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*|\.[0-9]+)([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|[δᵟ][-+]?|[-+][δᵟ]
```

Notices:

- depending of the regex engine you use, you have to activate the unicode mode to correctly parse and match characters out of the ASCII range like `δ`.
- depending of the availability of non-capturing groups in your regex engine, it's  better to use them instead of capturing ones.